# javascript string comparison of address that are resulted from google api

Tags: javascript, string, google-api, comparison

currently I am making address validation using google api, fortunately it is working properly, however I was asked to show the difference/changes that google api made with the user's input address. To make my question clear I will show an example

User's Input:
199 Freestone Road, *Wawick* QLD 4370, Australia

Google API output:
199 Freestone Road, *Sladevale* QLD 4370, Australia

what I'm trying to do is do something like this.

Google Change:
Wawick to Sladevale

I was thinking about using javascript string comparison to accomplish this task. Any function or example that you can suggest so that I can have a basis for my task. I was also thinking about the "street number" of the address will they also be counted as string or integers?, thank you for reading and every answer is appreciated.

Recently added:

Sir can I ask on how can I compare an address(string) word by word since an address that is outputted by the google api is divided into word by word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This javascript library can do this for you: http://ejohn.org/projects/javascript-diff-algorithm/

From their front page:

Sample Code

```
document.body.innerHTML = diffString(
   "The red brown fox jumped over the rolling log.",
   "The brown spotted fox leaped over the rolling log"
);
```

[image]

and the html version of its output:

```
<p>The <del style="background:#FFE6E6;">red</del> brown <ins style="background:#E6FFE6;">spotted</ins> fox  <del style="background:#FFE6E6;">jumped</del> <ins style="background:#E6FFE6;">leaped</ins> over the rolling log.</p>
```

Comment: tnx, I'll give it a shot